# MongoDB doesn't return all fields for some collections

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I recently started working on a Mongo database, and noticed while browsing through records that some collections weren't returning all their fields. Yet querying for all objects in the collection seems to return the complete data.

What can be the cause of this? My database is hosted on mLab, and I'm seeing this issue while browsing the database through their query editor and when connecting to the database using a GUI tool (such as MongoDB Compass).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide any examples of how data isn't being returned in its entirety?

Comment: @AdamHarrison Each record in a collection has about 20 fields, but only 10 of these fields are returned.

Comment: i have an example how you might fix this in meteor. Are you interested?

Comment: Can you provide sample documents? Please provide the query in question, and the output of the query. Doe the entries with missing fields have the same "_id".

Comment: If you really want an answer, you need to provide some concrete information and examples. Can't get exact answer to a vague question.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb compass is basically used to view data in graphical form so it just shows the fields which can be viewed in graphical form.

Eg. fields like a : ["1", "4", "8"] or array of objects

cant be viewed in graphical form.

Answer (score 0):

try adding limit to your request, by default is 10

Example the following operation returns at most 50 documents in the "bios" collection:

```
db.bios.find().limit( 50 )
```